# How to store reference data in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am writing a new smart contract for Hyperledger Fabric which will need few data points(kind of reference data) for calculation. These data points need to be shared across all the Orgs so that the outcome of the smart contract is same and can be verified.

Should I maintain even these data points on Fabric blockchain? If so, when an Org modifies(add/update) the data how the other Orgs accept or reject this transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer as I can't comment yet. I would recommend to keep the data on the ledger itself as the reference data is of small size and have to be synchronized across the organizations. One initialization function can be used in the chaincode to initialize the data(--isInit) before allowing regular transactions.